# Authorization failed while wget azure REST API

Tags: java, azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-monitoring

I am trying to collect azure metrics using REST api. I have a free subscription to azure account.

I am using the following wget to get the json message.

```
wget https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/RG_SOUTH_INDIA/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/linuxscal/metrics?api-version=2014-04-01
```

**XXXXXXX- is my subscription id.**

I get the following Error message.

```
Resolving management.azure.com... 13.67.231.219
Connecting to management.azure.com|13.67.231.219|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

What is wrong with my subscription/Authorization?!!

Thanks in Advance for your help guys!! Am Stuck!!

Comment: you don't need and 'API key' or similar to make your request? otherwise anyone could hit this link with your subscription id

Comment: U don't have username / password for authorization ? or only the link is enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include an `Authorization` header with a `Bearer` token in your call:

```
GET /subscriptions?api-version=2015-01-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: management.azure.com
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
```

Take a look at **armclient**, since you [really don't want to do all this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-rest-api/) by hand (or by *curl*):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/armclient

```
// ES6
import ArmClient, { clientCredentials } from 'armclient';

const client = ArmClient({ 
  subscriptionId: '111111-2222-3333333',
  auth: clientCredentials({
    tenantId: '444444-555555-666666666',
    clientId: '777777-888888-999999999',
    clientSecret: 'aaaabbbbbccccc' // or servicePrincipalPassword
  })
});
```

Your `/metrics` call becomes:

```
client.get('/resourceGroups/RG_SOUTH_INDIA/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/linuxscal/metrics', { 'api-version': '2014-04-01' })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
    console.log(res.headers);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @evilSnobu!! Thats true, i anyways wont using wget for it. I shall be using Java. When i am calling the REST API using Java, i am still getting the same error ie.Authentication error. It would be helpful if i get a java code for it!...Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the option `--user` and `--ask-password` wget will ask for the credentials. Below is an example. Change the username and link to your needs

```
wget --user=username --ask-password https://YOUR_URL
```

Comment: That's only good for HTTP Basic authentication - won't work with Azure ARM which expects a token: `Authorization: Bearer ToKeN=`